# Advertise Low Energy in Background Perpetually

Tags: android, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I want to advertise a UUID using BLE in the background for as long as possible. If a use case helps, imagine my app is a keyless entry app in which the phone is a peripheral and the lock is a central, and so must be always advertising when BLE is on. I have an application that contains a `BroadcastReceiver` that responds to the `ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` event and begins advertising if the current state is `STATE_ON`. My question is about persistence.

If I turn on Bluetooth without the app open, the advertising begins but is stopped some time later. If I open the app at any point the advertising is running and then force close it, the advertising stops, citing:

```
04-16 15:03:11.815  19411-19424/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ Binder is dead - unregistering client (5)!
04-16 15:03:11.815  19411-19425/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ Binder is dead - unregistering server (6)!
04-16 15:03:11.815  19411-19425/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ unregisterServer() - serverIf=6
04-16 15:03:11.816  19411-19425/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ deleteServices() - serverIf=6
04-16 15:03:11.816  19411-19425/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕ btif_gatts_delete_service
04-16 15:03:11.816  19411-19432/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕ btgatts_handle_event: Event 2010
04-16 15:03:11.817  19411-19446/? E/bt-att﹕ Active Service Found
04-16 15:03:11.817  19411-19432/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕ btapp_gatts_handle_cback: Event 11
04-16 15:03:11.817  19411-19432/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onServiceDeleted() srvcHandle=40, status=0
04-16 15:03:11.817  19411-19425/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕ btif_gatts_unregister_app
04-16 15:03:11.817  19411-19432/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕ btgatts_handle_event: Event 2001
04-16 15:03:11.820  19411-19432/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕ btapp_gatts_handle_cback: Event 6
04-16 15:03:11.821  19411-19444/? D/BtGatt.AdvertiseManager﹕ message : 1
04-16 15:03:11.821  19411-19444/? D/BtGatt.AdvertiseManager﹕ stop advertise for client 5
04-16 15:03:11.822  19411-19444/? D/BtGatt.AdvertiseManager﹕ app died - unregistering client : 5
04-16 15:03:11.822  19411-19444/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
04-16 15:03:11.828  19411-19432/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onAdvertiseInstanceDisabled() - clientIf=255, status=0
```

So it seems that the Bluetooth manager is bound in a way the calling application component. In order to remedy this, I created a `Service` that is started by the `BroadcastReceiver` and has the following characteristics:

- Enables LE advertising if Bluetooth is on
- Never calls `stopSelf()` unless Bluetooth is turned off (registered a receiver within the service to do this)
- Ignores multiple calls to `onStartCommand()` if is not the first call.
- Returns `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`

So if the service is reaped, it will clean up the Bluetooth code in `onDestroy()` and be restarted later. If the app is forced closed, the same thing will happen.

Is there a way that I can coerce Bluetooth to run without caring about what it is bound to? If not, does this seem like a viable structure? Please poke holes in it. EDIT: one thing I had concerns about was leaving this `Service` object alive forever and its effect on battery life. There should be away to just fire the BLE command and not consume system resources after that (aside from the power to the Bluetooth chip)

Comment: Just a comment on your design - it makes much more sense for the lock to be the peripheral and the app to be the central.

Comment: Perhaps, though this isn't the exact use case I'm implementing. The reason I chose to make the phone the peripheral is that it consumes less battery to constantly advertise than it does to constantly scan, and I am assuming the other peer has a power source. Further, I'd like to think of the phone as a server (in the client/server layer) and this usually pairs better with the slave role.

Comment: I don't know about Android devices but typically it uses much less power to run a receiver than a transmitter. Therefore I would think it would take less power to passively receive an advertisement. Certainly on iOS this is the case. The app registers the device or service it is interested in and then is suspended in the background with the OS waking it when the device is seen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common design problem with Android applications.
The problem with using an always on service is that the OS can kill it if low on resources. If that happens, your broadcast will effectively stop.
An always on service may also have a penalty on battery drain, depending on what actions happen within it.

A possible, yet not perfect solution will be to make your service a foreground service - this will prevent the OS from stopping it but it comes with a penalty, you MUST have an icon in the status bar for your app at all times, and if you're using Lollipop, also on the lock screen.

I solved this issue by a different design - I had a service that wakes up every X seconds, queries what it needs (instead of waiting for a broadcast), process the data, register itself to wakeup in X seconds and stop. If this solution fits you, it will definitely solve the dead service issue and possibly the battery drain one.

In any case, it looks like your service should be separated from the application for persistance, perhaps start it when the OS starts like WhatsApp does

Comment: Unfortunately, having the service as a foreground is not possibility, as this is supposed to run as a helper background service to the user. Regarding battery drain, the service is not actually executing code the whole time it is alive; rather, it starts Bluetooth LE advertising and then just does nothing, but stays alive so that the manager still has something to be bound to. I've tested it on some physical devices and the battery drain is unnoticeable. The always on service will restart itself when it is killed because of my `START_STICKY` flag, so that's not an issue either.

Comment: And what about polling for the data instead of listening to a broadcast? Is that a possibility in your scenario? If you can poll it then you can start your service in time intervals assuring it will not get killed by the OS